# Using a hashmap to iterate over a list of hashmaps

Tags: java, hashmap, iteration

I am using a hashmap to add similar values for each `aclLine` processed

```
for (String aclLine : refinedFileContents){
 if(Some condition)
 {
   staticVariablesMap.put("lineNumber", **lineNumber**); 
   staticVariablesMap.put("**srcHostName**", batchBean.getSourceIpAddress());
   staticVariablesMap.put("batchBean", batchBean);
}
}
```

Later I want to iterate over these hashmaps for each line and perform some actions specific to a given key, value pair (e.g. get the `srcHostName` for that `lineNumber`) and use it to process next steps. How can I iterate over these collected hashmaps for each `srcHostName` entry in the hashmap? Should I use ArrayList/List to store each instance of the hashmap? Is this feasible?

Comment: Hashmaps do not retain insertion order. I suggest parallel arrays/lists if that's what you are searching for.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, am using a ordering sequening added to the map, so that should be taken care of i think.Could you please tell how to iterate over that list for each hashmap entry , or where can i read for the same. Thanks

Comment: The fact that you're even referring to the entries in the HashMap as "lines" tells me there's a very high chance you're not using it the way it's intended. If you give some better indication of what the purpose of this is, I have little doubt that someone will have a better way of doing it all together for you.

Comment: @ Thor84no: I am refering to the "aclLine", as the line , my bad miss used it!My intention is to iterate over each aclLine, and when some condition is met then (probably am going on the wrong way from here , please correct ..), i want to add key/value pairs for some other entries i have in the existing Forloop, hence i used the hashmap , so that later i can retrieve the value for a key . since there are a lot of aclLines , there will be more than one hashmap.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like you should combine the attributes in your hashmaps into an object instead. Then you could just use one hash map.

```
public class AclLine {
    private long lineNumber;
    private String srcHostName;
    private Object batchBean; 
}

Map<AclLine> lines = new HashMap<AclLine>();
// Or maybe a List?
List<AclLine> lines = new ArrayList<AclLine>();
```

Or is there a reason you need these "parallel" map entries?

Comment: If there's only one value, why use a hashmap?

Comment: @Jimmt I can't tell if it's just one value from the example, but if it is, then yeah, maybe everything is in one data structure. But it might be useful with an "intermediate" data structure if you need to incrementally build the final result.

Comment: Yes @Nilsh , i have to keep a track of the srcHostName & other related details when iterating the For loop  , & then later use the srcHostName to get their Ipaddress & perform other operations with the Ipaddress.

Comment: I have got the solution as :  iterate over List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>(); how can i iterate over this list now for each map ..and get the key/value

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your question completely like you are putting values in only one hash map & you want to iterate hashmaps
You can iterate hash map like this.

```
Iterator<Entry<String, Object>> it = hashMap.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext())
{
    Map.Entry<String, Object> entry = (Map.Entry<String, Object>)it.next();
}
```